# find the probability of the following scenerio

Tags: probability

You roll 3 dice. 
Let Y be the random variable which is the smallest number rolled.Compute the probability mass function of Y.

so this is wht i have done: 
smallest number is k = total number of outcomes (|S|)-smallest number which is not k. ,where k=1,2,3,4,5,6

so in terms of probability:

P(Y=k)= 1 -(P(Y>k)+P(Y< k))= 1- P(Y > k)-P(Y < k)...(i)

Also P(Y=k)=1 therefore, P(Y < k)= 1 - P(Y >= k)...(ii)

putting (ii) into (i),

we get,

P(Y=k)=1-P(Y > k)-1+P(Y >= k)= P(Y >= k)-P(y > k)

now idk how to derive a formula for the pmf??

Comment: How many rolls have $6$ as the smallest number?  How many have $5$ as the smallest number?  Keep going.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb P(Y=6) = (1/6)^3 = 1/216$. Now for $\mathbb P(Y=5)$, consider the distinct outcomes in which the minimum is $5$, and sum them together.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Just count: $Y=6$ only happens if all throws come up $6$, so this has probability
$P(Y=6)=(\frac{1}{6})^3 = \frac{1}{216}$.

If $Y=5$ this means all $3$ throws are at least $5$ but not minimally $6$, so

$$P(Y=5)=(\frac{2}{6})^3 - P(Y=6) = \frac{7}{216}$$

So $P(Y \ge 5)=\frac{8}{216}$ and similarly $P(Y \ge 4) = (\frac{3}{6})^3$ and hence

$$P(Y=4) = P(Y \ge 4) - P(Y \ge 5) = \frac{27}{216} - \frac{8}{216} = \frac{19}{216}$$

and continue this way for $Y=3$, $Y=2$ and $Y=1$.

This should easily be generalisable for $k$ many $n$-sided dice:

Let $Y$ be the minimum value for $k$ many fair independent $n$-sided dice (with values $\{1, 2, \ldots n\}$, of course).

Then $P(Y=n)  =P(Y \ge n )=(\frac{1}{n})^k$ of course: all values must come up $n$.

In general $P(Y \ge m)$ can be found by considering that all $k$ dice must come up $m$ or higher, so in $\{m, \ldots, n\}$ which has $n-m+1$ members (out of possible $n$ values), so

$$P(Y \ge m)=(\frac{n-m+1}{n})^k$$

so $$P(Y=m) = P(Y \ge m) - P(Y \ge m+1) = (\frac{n-m+1}{n})^k - (\frac{n-(m+1)+1}{n})^k =\\ (\frac{n-m+1}{n})^k - (\frac{n}{m})^k = \frac{(n-m+1)^k-(n-m)^k}{n^k}$$

For your original question specialise back to $k=3$,$n=6$ to get

$$P(Y=m)=\frac{(7-m)^3 - (6-m)^3}{6^3} \text{ for } m=1,\ldots 6$$

Comment: yess i get this i have done this. i should have probably specified in the question i m looking for a general formula. the general formula is: ((6-k+1)^3-(6-k)^3)/6^3 . but i wanna know to they got this. many thanks.

Comment: yo bro thanks for the effort but i dont understand how you came to a general formula for this.

Comment: @PankajBhatt what part don’t you understand? I explain the formula.

Comment: I DONT GET "(=)=(≥)=(1)^" THIS PART. ALSO I AM JUST CONFUSED IN THE WHOLE DERIVATION.

Comment: @PankajBhatt the minimum value can only be (minimally) $n$ if all values are $n$ which happens with chance $\frac1n$ $k$ times.

Comment: yes okay that makes sense. nevermind it makes sense now